# C#: How to add certain elements from another list in another class and print out?

Tags: c#

I want to develop this option in a system that lists out all movies. The list genreList is created and declared private in another class and I am calling it in my main program.

part of the Movie Class:

```
public List<string> genreList = new List<string>();
public Movie() { }
public Movie(string tt, int dur, string cls, DateTime opendt, List<string> genrelist)
    {
        Title = tt;
        Duration = dur;
        Classification = cls;
        OpeningDate = opendt;
    }

    //methods
    public List<string> GetGenreList()
    {
        return genreList;
    }
```

And this is code in my main program:

```
List<Movie> MovieList = new List<Movie>();
        InitMovieList(MovieList);
if (option == 1)
            listAllMovies(MovieList);

static void getGenreList()
    {
        Movie moviegenre = new Movie();
        List<string> genreList = moviegenre.GetGenreList();

        genreList.Add("Action");
        genreList.Add("Adventure");
        genreList.Add("Comedy");
        genreList.Add("Fantasy");
        genreList.Add("Thriller");
    }

static void InitMovieList(List<Movie> MovieList)
    {
        Movie moviegenre = new Movie();
        List<string> genreList = moviegenre.GetGenreList();

        Movie m;

            m = new Movie("The Great Wall", 103, "NC16", Convert.ToDateTime("29-12-2016"), genreList);
            MovieList.Add(m);
        m = new Movie("Rogue One: A Star Wars Story", 134, "PG13", Convert.ToDateTime("15-12-2016"), genreList);
        MovieList.Add(m);
        m = new Movie("Office Christmas Party", 106, "M18", Convert.ToDateTime("15-01-2017"), genreList);
        m = new Movie("Power Rangers", 120, "G", Convert.ToDateTime("31-01-2017"), genreList);


    }

//list all movies
    static void listAllMovies(List<Movie> MovieList)
    {
        Movie moviegenre = new Movie();
        List<string> genreList = moviegenre.GetGenreList();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-30}{2,-10}{3,-20}{4,-15}{5,-15}", "No","Title","Duration", "Genre", "Classification", "Opening Date"));

        for(int i = 0; i<MovieList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-30}{2,-10}{3,-20}{4,-15}{5,-15}", i + 1, MovieList[i].Title, MovieList[i].Duration, genreList[i], MovieList[i].Classification, MovieList[i].OpeningDate));

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I am going to include certain elements like "Action, Adventure" or "Fantasy, Thriller" to one part of Movielist. The output should be something like this:

[image]

But what I have is this and a bundle of error messages:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

And that prevented the program from continuing to the part I need.

[image]

Please advise me on what to do! Thank you very much.

Comment: You should tell us which error messages you are getting.

Comment: I can be sure you run out of index in your `listAllMovies` method :))

Comment: Yes I just edited the question. Can you help?

Comment: You are iterating over `MovieLast`, but getting the genere `genreList[i]`, so  you are getting genre with the index of the movie, and if length of the movies is 10 and the length of the genres is 4, you will get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` after 4th iteration

Comment: I don't really understand, can you elaborate and advise on how to change this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problems in your code, firstly, in constructor of `Movie`, you should add line

```
this.genreList = genreList;
```

To add new movie to list:

```
Movie m = new Movie("The Great Wall", 103, "NC16", Convert.ToDateTime("29-12-2016"), new List<String>());
m.GetGenreList().Add("Action");
MovieList.Add(m);
```

And to print movie

```
for(int i = 0; i<MovieList.Count; i++)
{
      String genre = String.Join(",", MovieList[i].GetGenreList());
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-30}{2,-10}{3,-20}{4,-15}{5,-15}", i + 1, MovieList[i].Title, MovieList[i].Duration, genre, MovieList[i].Classification, MovieList[i].OpeningDate));
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("");
      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then delete all these code:

```
Movie moviegenre = new Movie();
List<string> genreList = moviegenre.GetGenreList();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing an index in `listAllMovies`. I've reformatted your code to make it easier to spot:

```
for(int i = 0; i<MovieList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
               string.Format(
                   "yourformatstring", 
                   i + 1, 
                   MovieList[i].Title, 
                   MovieList[i].Duration, 
                   genreList[i],     //  <----THE PROBLEM IS HERE
                   MovieList[i].Classification,         
                   MovieList[i].OpeningDate));

    }
```

You are using the same index `i` to get items from both your `MovieList` and your `genreList`. If your genrelist is shorter than your movielist, `i` will eventually become larger enough that it causes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when you try to retrieve `genreList[i]`.

---

The solution to this isn't clear cut, because I don't quite understand how you are setting up the relationship between Movie and Genre. Nowhere in your code do you set up a direct relationship between a specific movie and the genres it belongs to.

- You seem to pass a list of **all** genres into the Movie constructor. I would expect you to pass only the applicable genres
- In your Movie constructor, you never do anything with the genrelist that you have passed to it.
- While technically not causing a problem, you shouldn't store `genreList` inside each Movie class. It duplicates the same data for every Movie object; and I think it is indicative of a badly designed relationship between your movies and genres; which is the core of the issue you're faced with.

---

To still provide you with an answer, I'm going to assume that your Movie contains a `List<Genre> Genres;` where each `Genre` has a `Name` property.

This seems like what you want; even though it doesn't match with what you currently have.

```
for(int i = 0; i<MovieList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
               string.Format(
                   "yourformatstring", 
                   i + 1, 
                   MovieList[i].Title, 
                   MovieList[i].Duration, 
                   String.Join(",", MovieList[i].Genres.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()),     //  <----THE FIX IS HERE
                   MovieList[i].Classification,         
                   MovieList[i].OpeningDate));

    }
```

Comment: I've included the constructors for the Movie class in my question in the first block of code. I understand what you are saying about including the whole list of genres in place of only one or two element, but how do I change it? I thought that maybe adding genreList[i] can mean that the list prints index by index at the Genre part.

Comment: If `MovieList[i]` retrieves a `Movie` object that is inside the array at position `i`, then `genreList[i]` retrieves a `genre` object (in your case, a string) that is inside the array at position `i`. Same syntax; same meaning.

Comment: so I thought it would have worked the same way and print out the items one by one according to sequence